# Assign p-values to all data point in the population in order to demonstrate some of them are not normal

Tags: r, normal-distribution, p-value

a very naive question for some of you.
I have a population of 80000 data points. Some points in the population are highly skewed and they could be easily identified and visualized assigning them a p-value. I know that excluding those values, the population follow a nice normal distibution. What I ask you today is whether you can suggest me an approach to assigning a pvalue to each data point in the population where the null hypothesis is that the data contribute to the normality.

Thank you